# Real time drawing and saving as image(jpeg,png etc), process image, and again displaying the processed image

Tags: c++, image, user-interface, graphics

I am building an application in c++. Lets say for simplicity it gets an image and reverse it, and thus produces an output reversed image. Now, I am trying to make a user interface where a user draws and in real time he is able to see the reversed image.

That is my user interface should be able to save the image in real time(as my application needs image to be processed) and should load a result image(i.e. the output image of my application). I am not a graphics person and never built any user interface. So, don't know in which language it should be? Can we made it in c++ itself? So many questions... Any help?

Comment: Take a look at [JUCE](http://www.juce.com/). Full disclosure, I have a vested interest in the company that makes it, but they do have some great GUI tools.

Comment: But It seems to be too much. Its no less than qt.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, they both have free licenses?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV C++ library for image operations and basic interface (console + windows with images).

For building more advanced interfaces you can get a look at MFC or Qt and use OpenCV images with them also (or not).

Comment: As I want the user to be able to draw on the interface, can opencv be used?

Comment: OpenCV supports basic drawing functions (lines, circles etc.) but I'm not sure that it supports registering callbacks (for mouse inputs for example). For this task you may be forced to create a window with MFC (for example) for its callbacks and then display on it OpenCV matrix with image.